# Why am I getting "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" and it is shown?

Tags: angular

Why I get that error if I can see the value in the website ?...what's wrong ?

This is the code, basically, it's working but with that error in the console

**students.component.html**

```
 <li class="list-inline-item">
    <figure>  
       <img [src]="car.details.type.icon">
           <figcaption class="whiptype__value">{{ car.details.type.name }}</figcaption>
           </figure>
 </li>
```

**students.service.ts**

```
get(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get('assets/data/cars.json')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                   // .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getById(id: string): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.get().map(
      (res) => {
        let filterResult =  res.filter(item => {           
          return item.id === id 
        });
         // console.log(filterResult[0]);

        return filterResult[0];
      }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**students.component.ts**

```
getStudentById (id:number){
    this.studentService.getById(id)
      .subscribe(
        student => this.student = student,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }
```

this is how the data is return
**json response**

```
{id: "3", details:{ type:{ name: "ferrari", icon: "assets/icons/car-details/ferrari.png"  }}}
```

Comment: You're trying to access it before the data loads so you get the error, but then once it loads you can see it.

Comment: that make sense.... also when I do `car | json` I get a security error that's why I used `filterResult[0]` in the service

Answer (score 4):

Use safe navigation operator here because You're trying to access it before the data is received

```
<figure>  
 <img [src]="car?.details?.type?.icon">
 <figcaption class="whiptype__value">{{ car?.details?.type?.name }}</figcaption>
 </figure>
```